# Windows 7 will sleep, but wakes up immediately from hibernate

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hibernate, power-management

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu/Win7 setup with Windows on its own SSD. At first the Windows side would neither sleep nor hibernate. If I asked it to do either, the screens go off and it goes through the motions, then wakes right back up. I followed all the suggestions I could find, including

- going through Device Manager and unchecking "Allow this device to wake the computer" from every device that has a Power Management tab
- disabling Wake-on-LAN
- disabling hybrid sleep

`powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` gives me a blank line. After that, and a restart, I can now sleep, but I still can't hibernate. If I run `powercfg /lastwake`, it seems to only show what last waked my machine from sleep (Power Button), not from hibernation.

What might be keeping my machine from sleeping? How can I diagnose what's keeping it awake *specifically from hibernation*?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem in Windows 10. Have not found a solution yet.

Comment: I was never able to resolve this issue. I ended up wiping the Windows partition and reinstalling.